# How to save different settings for different pages in a chrome extension?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have created a chrome extension which consists of a popup where users can select and save different settings. I save these settings into localStorage, which is shared across all tabs. I want the user to be able to save different settings for different web pages.

This is what I want to work:

1. User can go to site 1 and save settings A
2. User can then go to site 2 and save settings B
3. Whenever the user returns to site 1, settings A are active (and displayed in popup)
4. Whenever user returns to site 2, settings B are active (and displayed in popup)

As of now, whenever the user changes settings on any page, these settings are active across all pages.

I have moved on from browser action to page action, but since I am saving the settings into the same localStorage it makes no difference.

The only idea I have is to save the url into the localStorage as a key and all the settings as the value. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least two solutions possible.

The first one is hinted at in your own question, as well as in Zig Mandel's answer. Yes, you can have preferences which are either in an object indexed by URL/hostname, e.g. `[hostname].option` or have multiple keys but prefixed by it, e.g. `[hostname+".option1"]`.

If you do go that route, especially the first variant, I highly recommend to switch from `localStorage` to [`chrome.storage.local` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage). It automagically serializes values for you. If you don't like the fact that it's asynchronous, you can make a page-specific cache for it that will load once and hide the async nature of `chrome.storage`.

The second solution is a heavy-hitter, but might be easier to work with; it is to employ a full-blown database in the form of [IndexedDB](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/).

Comment: Thank you, I used prefixing and it actually wasn't difficult to implement. I have a follow-up problem though: Now, if the user navigates to from site 1 to site 2 the settings only update after the user clicks on the popup icon. Once he clicks, the popup code runs and the settings are updated to those of site 2. Do you know if it is possible to run the popup.js on navigate to a new page?

Comment: _This is an unrelated question; I will answer once and will provide **no followup**. If you still need help - ask a new question._ Use a background page that listens to some events. Either [`chrome.tabs.onUpdated`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onUpdated) and other `tabs` events, or use [`chrome.webNavigation` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation) events.

Comment: I sensed it sounded like an unrelated question... Thank you so much for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of dumping all preferences in a single key, you can instead prefix your existing keys with the site root.